# Why did the Dothraki attack like this?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

When the Dothraki attack in the Loot Train Battle, why would they attack frontally? Wouldn't even medieval cavalry attempt to attack the flanks first?

Perhaps there is a historical model for a battle (minus dragons) for such an attack. I know the Battle of the Bastards was modeled on [Cannae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cannae), but I don't think I've heard of anything similar for the Loot Train battle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Because there were no flanks

[image]

The Lannisters are crossing a wide river ford with rocky ground &/or rock formations on either side.

[image]

[image]

Essentially, the Dothraki attacked the Lannisters **where they found them**. If they don't attack the Lannisters, right there and then, the Lannisters cross the ford and escape.

Comment: There's an aerial view at one point which shows the ends of the Lannister lines going either to the cliffs or the river (can't remember which). This again proves that there aren't any flanks.